# Using Mathematica to solve a nonlinear system of equations

Tags: nonlinear-system, mathematica

I'm looking for some sets of solutions for this nonlinear system. I only have to respect the conditions, getting numerical values to use for another thing:

$$\begin{align}
\delta_i &> 10 |\lambda_i|, \quad i=1,2 \tag{1,2} \\[4pt]
\Delta_i &> 10 |\Omega_i|, \quad i = 1,2,3 \tag{3,4,5}
\end{align}$$

$$\frac{|\lambda_1|^2}{\delta_1} = \frac{|\lambda_2|^2}{\delta_2} \tag{6}$$

$$\Delta_1 + \frac{|\Omega_1|^2}{\Delta_1} +\frac{|\Omega_3|^2}{\Delta_3} = \delta_1 + \frac{|\Omega_2|^2}{\Delta_2}  \tag{7}$$

$$\delta_2 + \frac{|\Omega_1|^2}{\Delta_1} +\frac{|\Omega_3|^2}{\Delta_3} = \Delta_2 + \frac{|\Omega_2|^2}{\Delta_2} \tag{8}$$

$$\begin{align}
\alpha &= \frac{\lambda_1 \Omega_1}{\delta_1} - \frac{\lambda_2 \Omega_2}{\delta_2} \tag{9} \\[4pt]
\beta &= \frac{\lambda_1 \Omega_1}{\Delta_1} - \frac{\lambda_2 \Omega_2}{\Delta_2} \tag{10}
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
\alpha &< 0.1 \tag{11} \\[4pt]
\beta  &< 0.1 \tag{12} \\[4pt]
|\lambda_1| &=1.0 \tag{13}
\end{align}$$

Naturally, $\delta_1, \delta_2, \Delta_1, \Delta_2$ and $\Delta_3$  are in   $\mathbb{R}$.

I'm using *Mathematica* to solve this nonlinear system of parameters (image below) by using `NSolve`, where I give some parameters and apply the conditions, but it's not working.

[image]

I know it is far away from a good strategy to attack this problem. Could someone help me with a code in *Mathematica* that **works setting a few parameters and the computer calculates the others (respecting all the conditions)?**

Comment: Just a quick note...  you may want to try the Mathematica Stack Exchange  site if you don't get any responses here... at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you, if I don't get any help from here, I'll ask there!

Answer (score 0):

I am not (from far away) an advanced user of Mathematica but I am not sure that *NSolve* can handle inequality constraints.

Let us consider that have $n$ equations $(f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_n)$. What I should do is to define
$$\Phi=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i^2$$ and use *NMinimize* for $\Phi$ where we can add as many constraints of any kind as we want.

Try it and let me know.

Comment: My dear, thank you for the response! I'm glad to try new things to solve this problem, and also learn something more about Mathematica. But I really don't understand how this function $\Phi$ would help. It seems to me is that it would find the minimal values for the parameters, which is not exactly what I want. Am I missing something?

Cheers!